# DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

What is happening here? I am trying to add data through ajax call with JSON datatype. But each time I try to add data it shows error as shown in the image.

[Rails log in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFwz2.png)

I think it always respond to html format but does not respond to json format.

```
def new
  @batch = Batch.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
    format.html
  end
end

def create
  @batch = Batch.new(batch_param)
  puts "/n/n/n/n name: #{@batch.name} /n/n/n/n"
  respond_to do |format|
     if @batch.save
       format.json { render json: @batch, status: :created, location: @batch }
       format.html { redirect_to @batch, notice: "Save process completed!" }
     else
      format.html {
        flash.now[:notice]="Save proccess coudn't be completed!"
        render :new
      }
      format.json { render json: @batch.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The before action(previously filter) should be stated near the top of your controller. As it is "before" your action code is not useful, If you have a line or more that says "before_filter....." simply change it to "before_action". The cheeky code may even be in your ApplicationController.

Comment: Just use a find and replace tool and replace `before_filter`  with `before_action`. The free Atom text editor has a pretty good find and replace that works in your whole project dir. Otherwise you can use grep `grep -rl before_filter app/controllers | xargs sed -i 's/before_filter/before_action/g' `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just depreciation warning which can turn into error if you upgrade your app to rails `5.1`, as clearly mentioned on the log you can resolve it by searching through your controller where you are using `before_filter` and replace it with `before_action`.

`before_action` does the same thing (run some code before the request hit the action in your controller) that `before_filter` does in earlier versions of rails.

Answer (score 0):

The `DEPRECATION WARNING` line is coming from your `application_controller.rb`, just change `before_filter` to `before_action` and this warning will go away.

The `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` is the actual error preventing the correct results from being returned. If your controller doesn't require the CSRF token for JSON requests, you should add a line like the following to your controller:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?
```